# Increase Java Heap Size in Spark on Yarn

Tags: java, apache-spark, out-of-memory, hadoop-yarn

How can I increase Java Heap Space using Spark on Yarn's extra java options?

This code is what I have so far that works:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 4g
```

This is what does not work:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 4g --extrajavaoptions '-Xmx2g'
```

I want to add spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions. The default is none. I know it should be a string of extra JVM options to pass to the YARN Application Master in client mode. I want to input something like -Xmx2g. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Is your executor running out of memory or the driver? If executor is running out of memory, `--executor-memory` is what controls the amount of memory allocated to each executor. Simply increase this number should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, way to use the command is as following.

```
--conf spark.executor.extrajavaoptions="Option" [Cluster]
--conf spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions="Option" [YARN]
```

But note that,

According to the Spark [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) documentation

> spark.executor.extraJavaOptions
>
> A string of extra JVM options to pass to executors. For instance, GC settings or other logging. Note that it is illegal to set Spark properties or heap size settings with this option. Spark properties should be set using a SparkConf object or the spark-defaults.conf file used with the spark-submit script. Heap size settings can be set with spark.executor.memory.

You shall not set heap size settings with this option Instead you can configure them in **spark-defaults** script.

example layout can be found here : [Git repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template)